# How to add css to wp_head depending on the user role?

Tags: css, wp-head

I think this question should have an easy answer for any developer but maybe I am wrong.

As much as I think, I can not understand why this snippet does not work to add a css style to the head depending on the role of the user visiting the site.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
    // Get the user object.
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Get all the user roles for this user as an array.
    $user_roles = $user->roles;

    // Check if the specified role is present in the array.
    if ( in_array( 'customer_2', $user_roles, true ) ) { ?>

    <style>

    .woofs-additional, .woofs-total {display: none!important;}

    </style>
    <?php
    }
} );
?>
```

It doesn't matter which role I write, since it doesn't work, however if I change it to
`if ( ! in_array( 'customer_2', $user_roles, true ) )`
the css is always loaded regardless of the user role.

Any charitable soul who can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `$user_id` coming from?

Comment: You need to set `$user_id`, Look into `get_current_user_id()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/

And make sure to check for null value when a user is not logged in before trying to get the user role.

Comment: Thank you for your help @kumar. You have pointed me in the right direction. I'm not a developer, but I'm slowly learning these kinds of details needed to make things work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of two fellow members of this forum I have managed to get the snippet working.

Here I leave the solution for any future answer seeker who happens to stop by.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
    
    //Get current user ID, if the user is logged in.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id(); }
    
    // Get the user object.
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Get all the user roles for this user as an array.
    $user_roles = $user->roles;

    // Check if the specified role is present in the array.
    if ( in_array( 'customer_2', $user_roles, true ) ) { ?>

    <style>

    .woofs-additional, .woofs-total {display: none!important;}

    </style>
    <?php
    }
} );
```